# If else condition not working properly React

Tags: reactjs

This is mine If else condition No matter what the className is its rendering the same form i am getting this Problem i want to solve this Problem

```
const square = "nodesquare";
var form;
if (square) {
  form = <form>
    <input className="process" type="text" name="process" id="process" />
    <Button type="primary" className="button center" onClick={this.clearAll}>Add</Button>
  </form>
  console.log('Form')
} else {
  form = <p>Nothing to Watch</p>
}

return (
  <div
    key={index}
    className={'node ' + node.className}
    id={node.id}
    ref={nodes => this.refs.nodes[index] = nodes}
    style={node.style}
    onClick={this.activeElem}
    square={square}>
    {form}
    <div className="delete-btn" onClick={event => this.deleteNode(event, node)}>X</div>
  </div>
)
            })}

      </div >
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Main Issue i was getting here is that i was in the Div binding Square thats why i am getting this error look here

```
             key={index}
             className={'node ' + node.className}
             id={node.id}
             ref={nodes => this.refs.nodes[index] = nodes}
             style={node.style}
             onClick={this.activeElem}
             square={square}
      >

thats why it was always true thanks for your Precious Time
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what is your problem.
As your `square` const is always equal to `"nodesquare"`, your code will always trigger the if condition and never the else.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

```
const square = "nodesquare";
var form;
if (square) { ....
```

It looks like `square`is allways `truthy`. Check the concepts of [truthy and falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) in javascript.